# MVC Get data from View to Controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, view, controller, actionresult

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("testingMethod","test",FormMethod.Get)) {
@Html.AntiForgeryToken()

@foreach (var item in Model) {
    @Html.DropDownList("dropDown_"+item.ConfigCode+"_ListName", (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewData["dropDown_"+item.ConfigCode])
}
                    .
                    .
                    .
                    .
}
<input type="submit" value="Save" />
```

Base on the above code, I successfully invoke the method "testingMethod" that in "testController" which returns me an URL:

```
http://localhost:59512/test/testing?__RequestVerificationToken=xxxxxxx&dropDown_KKK=3
```

In my ActionResult "testingMethod", I need to get this dropDown_KKK value which is 3. May I know what should I do in my method? I've tried edit the testingMethod as below:

```
public ActionResult testing(FormCollection collection){
    Debug.WriteLine(" ======= " + collection.GET("dropDown_KKK"));

}
```

Base on other post, it should work but Error occur at collection.GET which says System.Web.MvC.FormCollection does not  contain a definition of GET and no extension method 'GET' accepting a first argument blablabla...

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
collection["name"]
```

where `name` should be the name of your dropdown list.

Comment: There is nothing inside there, but as I said, from the URL i see "3" as value, is there any other way to access the value from URL?

Comment: You can use `Request.QueryString["dropDown_KKK"]`